# User in AzureAD has the role as User, but gets admin role on surface

Tags: azure, authentication, office365, azure-active-directory

I do AzureAD just for ActiveDirectory in combination with Office365 for access to the computers via the cloud.

Now I have two problems which can't be solved by the Office365 team who pointed me to the AzureAD team.

User XYZ has the role of a normal user in Azure AD and in Office 365, but after I had set up his Surface Pro 3 with his AzureAD login, he is a full admin on the machine and I can't change this. He is the only user on the Surface Pro 3. How can I force this that is only a User and not an Admin?

And secondly I want to remove the pin to login to Windows 10, I can remove it, but next time he logs in, the pin is required again, and I can't find any place to switch this login option off in AzureAD.

Anybody able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this question is more for superuser.com, actually it does not involve coding.

Comment: Thanks Benoit,

I was informed by Microsoft to search for my support for Azure via the community and there were just two options MSDN or stack overflow.

Will try somewhere else.